# Angular JS data binding not working for HTML5 reset button

Tags: angularjs, html

I my angular application, I'm using a reset button to clear the data in a text box. But the binding is not working properly with the reset button.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="ch.email"><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<div>{{ch.email}}</div>
```

When some text is typed in the text box, it appears in the div, But after resetting, The text in the div doesn't disappears.

[Please see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12590/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a button instead

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="changestore.sample">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" ng-click="reset()">
</form>
<div id="textdisplay">
    {{changestore.sample}}
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.reset=function(){
  $scope.changestore={};
}
```

**Working Fiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/aks0kmwe/

***HTML 5 reset button*** won't clear the ng-model, it clears only the value from the input box

**Working Example**:http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12591/

Comment: this would be an even more simple approach
 <input type="button" ng-click="changestore.sample = ''" value="reset">

Comment: This is the usual way of doing it. But as HTML 5 offers a reset button, I'm asking why is it not compatible with Angular

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Reset button will only clears the input control values but not the angular ng-model values that doesn't mean it is refreshing the page but it resets html form fields to their initial values. Here is working example

```
Html:
    <form>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <span data-ng-bind="name"></span>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" /> 
    </form>

Script:
      var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[])
                       .controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
                         $scope.name="Angular JS";
                       })
```

When you click on reset button it will clear textbox but not span tag value.After this you try to access name property value of scope using angular.element($0).scope() by doing inspect element on browser and it is still "Angular JS" only.